# MySQL User Defined Variable(s) in Create View statement

Tags: mysql

After doing some searching on stackoverflow, I couldn't find a solution to my problem. Hopefully it's not that hard.

**I'm trying to use a user-defined variable as part of a create view statement.**

I'm able to get the actual select statement to work using a Prepare command (shown second below). My problem is, when I try to run the "create view" part of the code, I keep getting errors. Without further ado, here's the MySQL code:

**Here's what I'd LIKE to do** (note the user-defined variable is at the very end in the "having" clause)

```
create view `co 1_class` as 
select all_class_qry.job_number, all_class_qry.companyid, all_class_qry.classcode, all_class_qry.class, all_class_qry.`standard title`, sum(all_class_qry.`# incmbts`) as `sumof# incmbts`,
 avg(all_class_qry.`avgofannual base salary`) as `avgofavg base`, sum(all_class_qry.elig) as `sumof# recv`, avg(all_class_qry.`avgofbonus salary`) as `avgofavg bonus`, 
 avg(all_class_qry.`total cash`) as `avgoftotal cash`, avg(all_class_qry.`avgofposition min`) as `avgofavg min range`, avg(all_class_qry.`avgofposition mid`) as `avgofavg mid range`, 
 avg(all_class_qry.`avgofposition max`) as `avgofavg max range`
from all_class_qry
group by all_class_qry.job_number, all_class_qry.companyid, all_class_qry.classcode, all_class_qry.class, all_class_qry.`standard title`, all_class_qry.companyid
having (((all_class_qry.companyid)=@form_fwid_num));
```

Here's as far as I've gotten with Prepare statements:

```
set @co_1_class_qry = 'select all_class_qry.job_number, all_class_qry.companyid, all_class_qry.classcode, all_class_qry.class, all_class_qry.`standard title`, sum(all_class_qry.`# incmbts`) as `sumof# incmbts`,
 avg(all_class_qry.`avgofannual base salary`) as `avgofavg base`, sum(all_class_qry.elig) as `sumof# recv`, avg(all_class_qry.`avgofbonus salary`) as `avgofavg bonus`, 
 avg(all_class_qry.`total cash`) as `avgoftotal cash`, avg(all_class_qry.`avgofposition min`) as `avgofavg min range`, avg(all_class_qry.`avgofposition mid`) as `avgofavg mid range`, 
 avg(all_class_qry.`avgofposition max`) as `avgofavg max range`
from all_class_qry
group by all_class_qry.job_number, all_class_qry.companyid, all_class_qry.classcode, all_class_qry.class, all_class_qry.`standard title`, all_class_qry.companyid
having (((all_class_qry.companyid)=?));';

prepare stmt1 from @co_1_class_qry;
execute stmt1 using @form_fwid_num;
```

Again, I'm 100% able to run these three commands ^ but I would like to put

```
'create view `co 1_class` as'
```

right at the beginning of the @co_1_class_qry string.

I can only imagine there has to be a way to use a user-defined variable as part of a create view/table statement, as well as a better way to do this. Thank you in advance!

Note: Here's the error message from MySQL I keep getting -

```
09:27:09    prepare stmt1 from @co_1_class_qry  
Error Code: 1351. View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter    0.062 sec
```

Comment: Couldnt you just assign `create view 'co 1_class' as` to a variable like `$thisvariable = "create view 'co 1_class' as "` and then somehow trigger that variable when needed? `set @co_1_class_qry = '$thisvariableselect all_class_qry.job_number, all_class_qry.comp...`

Comment: Hmm, I could do something like that, but I don't need the

    create view `co 1_class` 

string on command. I need it always. And it seems to not work as a full statement still.

Comment: UPDATE: I actually ended up using the
    "create table"
command instead of the 
    "create view"
command because it allows for variables in the select statement.